# Apache Spark writing to s3 failing to move parquet files from temporary folder

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have an 8 hour job (spark 2.0.0) that writes the results out to parquet using the standard approach:

```
processed_images_df.write.format("parquet").save(s3_output_path)
```

It executes 10000 tasks and writes the results to a _temporary folder, and in the last step (after all the tasks completed) it copies the parquet files from the _temporary folder, but after copying about 2-3000 files it fails with the following (first I thought this was a temporary s3 failure, but I rerun 3 times and getting the same error):

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted. 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:149) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:487) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237) 
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) 
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280) 
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128) 
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) 
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443 failed to respond 
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:259) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:232) 
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272) 
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) 
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:326) 
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:277) 
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestPut(RestStorageService.java:1143) 
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.copyObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:2117) 
        at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.copyObject(StorageService.java:898) 
        at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.copyObject(StorageService.java:943) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.copy(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:320) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy20.copy(Unknown Source) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.rename(NativeS3FileSystem.java:645) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:345) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:362) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:310) 
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:46) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.commitJob(WriterContainer.scala:222) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:144)
        ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution I found for this problem is to update Hadoop to 2.7 and set

```
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 2
```

In Spark 1.6 there was an alternative version of the fileoutputcommiter that wrote directly to s3, but it got deprecated in spark 2.0.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10063

Comment: I spent half my day searching for this line above! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Check out for more info: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/append-slow-with-spark-2.0.0.html